# How to align a content inside <p> tag in HTML?

Tags: html

I'm trying to align a paragraph inside a `<p>` tag in a HTML page as depicted in the following image. Can anyone suggest a way to do it as the middle content is a little bit moved to the right side.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdomy.png)

Comment: Please provide suggestions without using any CSS.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Take a look at the guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to help other people to reproduce your issue and try to help you better. :)

Comment: @user9462524 — Under normal circumstances, that is an unreasonable requirement. CSS is the tool designed for handling presentation of webpages. Why are you rejecting it? (If you have a good reason then it is likely going to rule out some other options too, so it is important to know what it is).

Answer (score 1):

If you truly don't want to use any CSS, then sarkasronie is correct that the only way to do that would be with a white image.  That being said, you can place the css directly within the HTML document:

```
<p>
    Content outside of indentation...
    <span style="margin-left: 100px">Indented content</span>
    More outside content.
</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

its easy you should use the PRE tag instead of paragragh to write as it is you want for example..

```html
<pre>
               My Bonnie lies over the ocean.

         My Bonnie lies over the sea.

                My Bonnie lies over the ocean.
   
         Oh, bring back my Bonnie to me.
</pre>
```